# UITableViewController, getting bounds of visible area

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

I've got this question. In my app I have many cells. When user clicks on something I'm loading VC and pushing it. To indicate this behaviour I'm displaying a subview which informs that now application is loading. Problem is, when user scrolls down and taps on cell my subview still is on the top of the tableView thus user isn't seeing it.

I need to change frame of my subview so my user can see it. I want this frame to be the center of the current view. How I can do that?

Fore example: My content is 800 pixels worth of height, now I'm displaying at 400 pixels subview with specific information about loading. When my user scrolls down to a cell that is at 2400 pixels, I'm still displaying subview at 400 pixels and thus it is unviewable by user.

I was trying to calculate new frame.origin.y by checking y of a cell that is tapped. Problem is the cell at 2400 pixels could be the first cell user is seeing or the last one, so how I can get the middle of the screen?

Edited with some screens:

When I select first time:
[image]

When I select after scrolling down big time:
[image]

Comment: Your description isn't very clear, if your can put an image in your post it would help.

Comment: Ok, here you go I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it looks like you have done here is added the loading view as a subview to the UIScrollView. You need to add the loading viewController into the parentView after the scrollview.

If this cant be done because your viewController is a subclass of UIScrollview, change it to a regular UIViewController subclass but implement the scrollView protocols and then do as i have said above. Other than that you would have to map the frame of the loading ViewController to the offset on the scrollView-not a good idea.